# I can not get Moltin Laravel Cart to install

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

I can not get Moltin Laravel Cart to install. It always tells me that `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages`.

Get this output from the Terminal:

**Problem 1**

- Installation request for `moltin/laravel-cart dev-master` -> `satisfiable by moltin/laravel-cart[dev-master]`.
- `moltin/laravel-cart dev-master` requires `moltin/cart dev-master` -> `no matching package found`.

**Potential causes:**

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

I just have added the requirement in the composer.json file as the tutorial says

```
...
"require": {
"laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
"intervention/image": "dev-master",
"moltin/laravel-cart": "dev-master"
},
...
```

Could anybody tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 12):

Change

```
minimum-stability: 'stable' to minimum-stability: 'dev'
```

Then after

```
minimum-stability: 'dev'
```

just add

```
"prefer-stable": true
```

like such:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define all the required packages first as dev-master as this will avoid the required packages not loading due to no stable versions being found. i.e.

```
"require": {
"laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
"moltin/currency": "dev-master",
"moltin/tax": "dev-master",
"moltin/cart": "dev-master",
"moltin/laravel-cart": "dev-master"
},
```

Changing the minimum-stability to dev at the bottom of composer.json will also achieve the same. i.e.

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `Composer` question, not really about `Laravel 4`.

In your `composer.json` you likely have a setting called:

```
minimum-stability: 'stable'
```

if it's not `stable` then it's something higher than `dev`.

`moltin\cart` has no stable releases.  There is a write up of what you can do here:

https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html

The easiest fix would be to add:

```
'moltin/cart': "dev-master",
```

to your `require` section of `composer.json` *before* `moltin\laravel-cart`.

Answer (score -1):

After added composer.json and type "composer update" (Windows) or "php composer.phar install" it will tell you the percent completely 100% downloaded of four php packages instead of "composer install".